# Can I change the classname in a script when I change page

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

Hallo All,
I have a problem. I have written a very extensive script to change my body-background from a page-specific background-image to an other background-image. For refrence:
My 'mypage.html' has a default background of class='image1' defined in the **default** stylesheet.
I have written a script to change this to class='image10' or class='image11', which are defined in the **persistent** stylesheet. (Believe me, this is the short version, but this part works... well, is going to. No questions here.)
My 'otherpage.html' has a default background of class='image2' defined in the **default** stylesheet and I want to be able to change this as well to the same 'image10' and 'image11' from the **persistent** stylesheet.
Both default backgrounds have multiple differently colored versions in **alternate** stylesheets... Change the stylesheet and class='image1' links to another version of the image.
All this is directed by cookies that are page specific as well. This makes finding a solution quite important, because otherwise I would have to set cookies for every single page. Which I find unacceptable.
**My question is**, do I have to copy/past the whole script to my 'otherpage.html' and change al the 'image1's to 'Image2's or is there a way to javascript something like:

```
if(HTML = 'otherpage.html') {
   (".image1" = ".image2")
}
```

Excuse my very amateuristic script. I have looked all over, but I wouldn't even know how to search for this... Hope someone can help, otherwise copy/past it is ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little script here

```
var currentPage =  window.location.pathname;

if (currentPage == "/somepage.html") {
   // change the body class name
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = "image2";
}
```

You can use a switch statement if you have multiple pages to test.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction. Gonna try it tomorrow. Allready looking forward to it ;)

Comment: I have reformulated this question in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806406/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-direct-alternative-classes).

Answer (score 0):

You can control the styles(background and other styles) through the base class which you can set it to body tag of the document or any root container. On page load check the page name and set the class names accordingly.

```
if(page == "otherPage"){
  document.body.className = "image2";
}
```

Now all the classes falling under image2 will be applied.

Comment: I have reformulated this question in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806406/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-direct-alternative-classes).