# How do I set a variable to direct alternative classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

This is a reposting of **[a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804262/can-i-change-the-classname-in-a-script-when-i-change-page)**. Other question wasn't formulated good enough. I won't delete the other question, because it might be usable for others.
Hello All,
I have a javascript/jquery script, containing cookies and directing background-image-classes for the body tag, via`<body id='body_bg'>`. Small portion of this script for example:

```
$('.somebuttons_class').live('click', function(){
  $('#body_bg').removeClass('image10').addClass('image1');
  $.cookie('bg_for_the_day', 'image1', { path: '/', expires: 1 });
});
```

In this piece of script the user is displaying an optional 'image10' to 'body_bg', but wants to change this back to the default image of 'image1'.
This script is now in the head section of my 'mypage.html' page. I would like to move this to an external js-page.
**Problem is:**
as you can see, I have called the default class for the body by name, 'image1'. But the default class for 'myotherpage.html' is 'image2' and for 'yetanother.html' it is 'image3'. This means I have to copy/past the whole script to 'myotherpage.html' and change all the 'image1's into 'image2's. That is a lot of dubble code, but it would work. However, as shown, my cookies give me back value='image1' as well. So that's not gonne work for any of my other pages at all!
**Question:** How do I set a variable of say 'default', instead of class='image1' or 'image2', in my javascript? And how do I input the script to translate 'default' back to 'image1' if the page is 'mypage.html', but use 'image2' if the page is 'myotherpage.html'?
Just to give you an impression of what I mean:

```
var currentPage =  window.location.pathname;
var default;
if(currentPage == "mypage.html"){
  default = "image1";
}
if(currentPage == "myotherpage.html"){
  default = "image2";
}
```

Then the previous script is going to look something like this:

```
$('.somebuttons_class').live('click', function(){
  $('#body_bg').removeClass('image10').addClass('default');
  $.cookie('bg_for_the_day', 'default', { path: '/', expires: 1 });
});
```

I, by now have learned quite a bit about javascript, this feels like getting to the next level ;) I thank you in advance for your help.
**Edit:** After the answer I got I tried again. I didn't get it working. I decided to make a simplefied version of the actual script and post it here. Please check it out, if you have some time to spare. 
You can **[download the testpage here](http://maartenkamps.nl/styletest.zip)**. Every help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok apart for this line:

```
 $.cookie('bg_for_the_day', 'default', { path: '/', expires: 1 });
```

which should be:

```
 $.cookie('bg_for_the_day', default, { path: '/', expires: 1 });
```

so that the value of the cookie is your variable (in your code the value of the cookie is always "default"

Comment: Thanks Nicola, I was overjoyed with your answer and rechecked my code. But I still can't get it working. I have now added 2 links to my question, in hopes someone can make this work in a simplefied version of the actual script. Please have a look. Thanks at forhand.